# Why NgForm object gives incorrect values for valid and Invalid properties

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm an angular beginner, and I wanted to disable the submit button if the form is invalid, and enable it once the form become valid.
I used the NgForm variable to obtain the form validity status:

```
<form #currencyForm="ngForm">

// some input elements with sync validations and async validations
// some disabled elements with no validation at all (just default values)

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit"  [disabled]="currencyForm.invalid" (click)=submitClicked(currencyForm)>Submit</button>
</form>
```

the `submitClicked()` method used to log the currencyForm object, please notice the values of the valid\invalid properties:
[image]

while the form looks like this:
[image]

so the form is invalid but the log showing that form is valid, that's why the submit button is always enabled..
and to fix that I need to understand why form values are invalid..
thanks a head

Update, Form Code:

```
<form class="example-form" #currencyForm="ngForm" >
    <mat-dialog-content>
      <div class="example-container">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input type="text" matInput #currency_name maxlength="30" placeholder="Currency Name" required [(ngModel)]="currency.name" name="name" [formControl]="nameFormControl" >
            <mat-hint align="end">{{currency_name.value?.length || 0}}/30</mat-hint>
                <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.invalid && (nameFormControl.dirty || nameFormControl.touched)">{{getNameErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>  

            </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input type="text" matInput #currency_symbol maxlength="3" placeholder="Symbol" required [(ngModel)]="currency.symbol" name="symbol" [formControl]="symbolFormControl">
            <mat-hint align="end">{{currency_symbol.value?.length || 0}}/3</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="symbolFormControl.invalid && (symbolFormControl.dirty || symbolFormControl.touched)">{{getSymbolErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input  matInput #decimals maxlength="1" placeholder="Decimals after point" required [(ngModel)]="currency.decimals_after_point" name="decimals_after_point" [formControl] = "decimalsFormControl">
            <mat-hint align="end">{{decimals.value?.length || 0}}/1</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="decimalsFormControl.invalid && (decimalsFormControl.dirty || decimalsFormControl.touched)">{{getDAPErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
 </div>

    <section class="example-section">

        <mat-checkbox  [disabled]="true" [value]="data.functional_currency_exist" [checked] = "data.functional_currency_exist" >Operational</mat-checkbox>

    </section>
 </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
    <div class="button-row">
         <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit"  [disabled]="currencyForm.invalid" (click)="submitClicked(currencyForm)">Submit</button>
         <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click) = "closePanel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] or at least your code.

Comment: @trichetriche post updated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way.

```
[disabled]="!currencyForm.valid"
```

instead of doing this

```
[disabled]="currencyForm.invalid"
```

I do remember that I once had the same issue as described above. And doing it my way solved it. Sorry, but I can't explain it in more detail as there are no more details. Somehow the invalid-flag does not work properly but valid does.

Comment: @Furqan: I added a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: I do remember that I once had the same issue as described above. And doing it my way solved it. Sorry, but I can't explain it in more detail as there are no more details.